# MobX. @observable works but @computed don't

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have the following code:
It works fine if `_isFavorite` variable is `public observable`. But once I change it to `@computed`, it triggers only once. But further `@action` callings don't trigger `@computed`.

This works fine, once `isFarovite` is changed:

```
class Cat {
    @observable public isFavorite = false;

    constructor() { ... }

    @action public toggleFavorite() {
        this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work if `_isFavorite` is changed:

```
class Cat {
    private _isFavorite = false;

    constructor() { ... }

    @computed public get isFavorite() {
        return this._isFavorite;
    }

    @action public toggleFavorite() {
        this._isFavorite = !this._isFavorite;
    }
}
```

I think I might miss the core concept of how "computed" works, but I can't figure out how I should change my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because `computed` value should be applied on some `observables`.

It actually checks which `observables` are used inside of it, and register itself as an observer of it & **caches** the result.

```js
class Cat {
    @observable private _isFavorite = false;

    constructor() { ... }

    @computed public get isFavorite() {
        return this._isFavorite;
    }

    @action public toggleFavorite() {
        this._isFavorite = !this._isFavorite;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Indeed works. It wasn't obvious to me to mark a private variable as `@observable` because it is not used directly in render() method.

Comment: It is not related to private / public but to the fact that it was used in observers, as I've explained, `computed` is the same as `observer` on a component :]